# if constexpr usage for variable length element Get<>

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I am trying to get the second element of the list, but I get an error:

```
    ||=== Build: Debug in hellocpp17 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
/home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp|67|error: no matching function for call to ‘Get<2>::Get(std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int>&)’|
/home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp|40|note: candidate: constexpr Get<2>::Get()|
/home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp|40|note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided|
/home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp|40|note: candidate: constexpr Get<2>::Get(const Get<2>&)|
/home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp|40|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int>’ to ‘const Get<2>&’|
/home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp|40|note: candidate: constexpr Get<2>::Get(Get<2>&&)|
/home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp|40|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int>’ to ‘Get<2>&&’|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template<unsigned n>
struct Get
{
    template<class X, class...Xs>
    constexpr auto operator()(X x, Xs...xs)
    {
        if constexpr(n > sizeof...(xs) )
        {
            return;
        }
        else if constexpr(n > 0)
        {
            return Get<n-1> {}(xs...);
        }
        else
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
};



int main()
{
    list<unsigned> l = { 7, 5, 16, 8 };
    unsigned l2 = Get<2>(l);

    cout << l2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

If I instantiate a `Get<2>`, this error is reported by the compiler

```
unsigned l2 = Get<2>()(l);

/home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp|67|error: void value not ignored as it ought to be|
```

Comment: You need to instantiate `struct Get<2>` -- use `unsigned l2 = Get<2>()(l)`

Comment: @Fred Error: /home/idf/Documents/c++/hellocpp17/main.cpp|67|error: void value not ignored as it ought to be|

Comment: Also you passed to `Get<2>()` a single `std::list<unsigned int>` when you ought to pass to it multiple arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with

```
unsigned l2 = Get<2>{}(7, 5, 16, 8);
```

The first problem in your code is that

```
Get<2>(l);
```

isn't a call to `operator()` of `Get<2>`; it's a construction of a `Get<2>` object with a `std::list` parameter.

Unfortunately there isn't a `Get<2>` constructor that receive a `std::list`.

The second problem in your code is that if you call the `operator()` of `Get<2>` as you think

```
Get<2>{}(l)
```

where `l` is a `std::list`, you pass a single argument; not a variadic list of arguments. And you can use the list `l` only run-time, not compile time as you want.

Unfortunately the `Get<2>{}(7, 5, 16, 8)` way (the `operator()` that receive a variadic list of arguments) is incompatible with a variable that contain a list.

I mean... you can't do something as follows

```
auto l = something{7, 5, 16, 8};

Get<2>{}(l);
```

But, if you modify the `operator()` to receive a `std::integer_sequence` as follows

```
template <template <typename X, X...> class C,
          typename T, T I0, T ... Is>
constexpr auto operator() (C<T, I0, Is...> const &)
 {
   if constexpr (n > sizeof...(Is) )
      return;
   else if constexpr (n > 0)
      return Get<n-1>{}(C<T, Is...>{});
   else
      return I0;
 }
```

you can pass through a `l` variable as follows

```
auto l { std::integer_sequence<int, 7, 5, 16, 8>{} };

unsigned l2 = Get<2>{}(l);
```

Comment: @Ivan - Answer improved with an alternative way to write the `operator()`. Hope this helps.